# Where are the cookies in the native android browser stored?

Tags: android, cookies

Basically, I'd like to know if there's a specific folder I can look in and copy/paste cookie data from. I've tried looking around myself but to no avail. Google didn't help much either.

If they aren't stored to a folder that is directly accessible, is there any other way to get to them?

I'm on the Android 2.2 (Froyo) version if that helps. THANKS. :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For security reasons, each application stores its data in a private sandbox/folder and other applications cannot access it. Refer Cookie Management details in Webview http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Answer (score 7):

We ran into a particular scenario where we wanted to see how our website cookies were re-acting with a device.   We were able to view the database the cookies are stored using "adb shell" on an emulated device.
After running the shell, we were able to track the cookies to a database using the following command.

```
sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.browser/databases/webviewCookiesChromium.db
```

and the select statement here:

```
select * from cookies;
```

the column list can be view by using the following command:

```
pragma table_info(cookies);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a WebView within an application to show the page in question you can find the cookies in the db file:

```
/data/data/your.apps.package.name/databases/webview.db
```

Once you've got that db you can do the same thing from Mike's answer to inspect the cookies.

```
select * from cookies
```